# Using single IOWebSocketChannel for multiple pages

Tags: flutter, websocket

I'm developing a chat application. I couldn't decide how to deal with the socket connection then turned to a temporary solution. It has a `static IOWebSocketChannel` that is reassigning with `onGenerateRoute`. As I know It's a really bad practice if you want to use single channel. So I need a better way of dealing with socket

I want to connect to channel once all over the app as a singleton and manage it on various pages but when I want to use same channel's stream on two different PageRoute, I get 'this stream is already listening' error.

How can I deal with this situation?

----- Update

asBroadcastStream doesn't work in my using.

[GitHub myapp.dart](https://github.com/ataberkw/Flutter-Node.js-Advanced-Chat/blob/master/client-Flutter/lib/myapp.dart)

[One usage](https://github.com/ataberkw/Flutter-Node.js-Advanced-Chat/blob/master/client-Flutter/lib/UI/chatting.dart) of asBroadcastStream. [Another usage](https://github.com/ataberkw/Flutter-Node.js-Advanced-Chat/blob/master/client-Flutter/lib/UI/chatting.dart) of asBroadcsatStream. Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert stream to BroadcastStream which can have multiple listeners.

```
IOWebSocketChannel channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect("wss://echo.websocket.org");
Stream stream = channel.stream.asBroadcastStream();
```

Comment: Two days ago I tested and see it was working. Then went to my hometown. Right now, as I test, everything is on the same state but even if I use asBroadcastSteam, I get 'Stream has already been listened to.' error. I updated my post with GitHub links.